# How to fail the test case - Cucumber with Groovy

Tags: groovy, cucumber

When I check the particular cucumber step in the step definition file, if the condition is false, I wanted to make that particular test case should be stopped and fail and continue with the next test case.

If I have to use the `FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE`, how to code the line?

```
@When("User enters the (.*) in the Login")
def user_enter_userid_in_the_Login(String uid) {
if (uid=='')
    /** FAIL the TEST CASE **/
else
    WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/ORTC01/Page_/input_userid'), uid,
     FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
    WebUI.delay(5)
}
```

Comment: `assert uid!=''` or just `assert uid`

Comment: Thank You, jonrsharpe. **How do I write the code ? Please mention it. How to fail the test case ?**

Comment: def user_enter_userid_in_the_Login(String uid)  {                                          
assert uid!=''                                                   
WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/ORTC01/Page_/input_userid'), uid, FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE) WebUI.delay(5)     }                             **otherwise the test will be failed ?**

Answer (score 0):

```
def user_enter_userid_in_the_Login(String uid) {
    assert uid!='' //this will fail test if uid==''
    ...continue success code
}
```

also possible to provide the error message

```
assert uid!='' : "the parameter 'uid' could not be empty"
```

it approximately corresponds to:

```
if(uid=='')throw new Exception("the parameter 'uid' could not be empty")
```

Comment: **perfect, daggett. Thanks for your clarification.**